# RadioButton JS doesn't work with input ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input ids when called through JS doesn't work. What I need is to make changes to the input fields such as hide & show, set input property to "required" and remove property "required" 
through ids called in JS when a radiobutton is clicked. I did put "div" referred from a source, edited some and come up with this. I have here my complete codes for my problem so I can deliver my problem understandably.

CSS & JS in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

    .red{ background: #ff0000; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

            if($(this).attr("value")=='red'){
                        $(".box").hide();
                        $(".red").show();
                        $('input[type="text"]').hide();
                        $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
                    }

            if($(this).attr("value")=='rd1'){

                var show1 = getElementById('showthis1');
                var show2 = getElementById('showthis2');
                $('input[type="text"]' + show1).show();
                $('input[type="text"]' + show1).attr("required","required");

                $('input[type="text"]' + show2).hide();
                $('input[type="text"]' + show2).removeAttr("required"); 
                $('input[type="submit"]').show();
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=='rd2'){

                var show1 = getElementById('showthis1');
                var show2 = getElementById('showthis2');
                $('input[type="text"]' + show1).hide();
                $('input[type="text"]' + show1).removeAttr("required");

                $('input[type="text"]' + show2).show();
                $('input[type="text"]' + show2).attr("required","required"); 
                $('input[type="submit"]').show();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

for the body:

```
<from action="">

<label><input type="radio" name = 'selecthere' value="red"> red</label>
<label><input type="radio" name = 'selecthere' value="rd1"> rad1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name = 'selecthere' value="rd2"> rad2</label>

<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div> 
        <input type="text" name="here1"  id="showthis1"  required/>
        <input type="text" name="here2"  id="showthis2" required/>        
        <input type="submit" id="showthis" value="Click"/>
</form>
```

Do I need to reconstruct this one? I really need help about this. Any help may add additional idea to me in the field of page development. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- You have to use `document.getElementById`

2.- To optimize code use `switch`

3.- As you are getting the elements by ID and then you pass them to JQuery, you simply can pass them use  this:

```
$("#showthis1").hide();
$("#showthis1").removeAttr("required");
```

instead of

```
 var show1 = document.getElementById('showthis1');
 var show2 = document.getElementById('showthis2');
 $('input[type="text"]' + show1).show();
 $('input[type="text"]' + show1).attr("required","required");
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gFZpC/)**